# proving that given independence of RV $X$ and $Y$,$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]$.

Tags: independence

hi i really need some help with this question. I need to prove given that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent,then $X$ and $Y$ are mean-independent.(i.e $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]$. How do i go about this?   THANKS!!

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]$?

Comment: Use the fact that when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the conditional distribution $f_{X/Y}=f_{X}$ to get $E[X/Y]=E[X]$

Comment: Yes thats what i meant. sorry about that. Can you help me out?

Comment: o okay, i ll try that out and see what comes up.thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then, for any Borel measurable set $A$, $X$ and $(Y\in A)$ are also independent. Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{Y\in A}E(X\mid Y) dP &= \int_{Y\in A} X dP\\
&=\int_{\Omega} X \,\mathbb{I}_{Y\in A}dP\\
&=E(X \,\mathbb{I}_{Y\in A})\\
&=E(X) E(\mathbb{I}_{Y\in A})\\
&=E(E(X)\,\mathbb{I}_{Y\in A})\\
&=\int_{\Omega}E(X)\,\mathbb{I}_{Y\in A} dP\\
&=\int_{Y\in A} E(X) dP.
\end{align*}
That is, $E(X\mid Y) =E(X)$.